# What will the partnership between Visual Studio and Stack Overflow look like for VS "bing code search"?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, third-party

An article written today titled [Introducing Bing Code Search for C#](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-bing-code-search-for-c/) indicates that (emphasis mine)

> "We partnered with MSDN, **StackOverflow**, Dotnetperls and CSharp411 to deliver some of the best code samples straight to Visual Studio."

What will this partnership entail, and how will interaction with SO content be tracked in Visual Studio (i.e. will voting and view counts be affected)?

Comment: Looks like Microsoft is implementing their own version of [Stack Sort](http://gkoberger.github.io/stacksort/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Microsoft is doing all of this using only the information we make publicly available ([the API](http://api.stackexchange.com), [data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange), maybe data from the Bing crawler). There isn't actually any formal partnership at all on this project, other than them using our data.

If you look at the project, there isn't actually any interaction with SO content in the add-in: it just scrapes snippets of code and puts them into your source. If you want to vote, comment, edit, answer, etc. you can follow a link to the original source. View counts will not be affected (API hits do not count toward view count).

Comment: The "partnered with" in the article seems to be a bit misleading.